# Python connect to serial port (PyQt GUI)

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial, qtserialport, qtserial

I'm trying to use python and Qt designer to have serial term like software program.
I can open the COM port without any problem. But I couldn't find a good example to detect usb device plug in and unplug event in Python with pyserial or Qtserial.

Is there a way to update connected USB-to-Serial type of device list dynamically in python?

I'm using Windows10 + Python 3.x + PyCharm + pyserial + Qt designer.